# vscode+mingw interesting debug situation

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64

I'm pretty new to c language and I'm working with vscode. The interesting thing is that when I set "stopAtEntry" and "externalConsole" to "false" in the launch.json code in the project, there is no debugging, the output comes directly to the terminal. But if I do "true" I can inspect every row. Is this a normal situation =?

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "gcc.exe - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw32\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: According to the manual [Configuring C/C++ debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference) the flag `stopAtEntry` is required to make the debugger stop at program entry. Without that flag the debugger just starts the program and without a breakpoint it just runs to the end. Not sure what makes this behaviour interesting.

Comment: somewhere "getch();" I've heard that it replaces him, but his mission was different. Sorry for my ignorance, thank you for your help.

Comment: `getch` can only prevent the terminal from closing immediately and wait until you press enter key. But if you don't tell the debugger to stop program execution somewhere, you cannot investigate variables or step through instructions. If you set a breakpoint in your code, I would expect, it to stop even without that flag set.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.